# JQuery Execution Order of Deferred Object Callback Hooks (Promise vs. Complete)

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I have a locally hosted project with a view that makes an AJAX request to the server.  The code is duplicated in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KRLacey/c8wq9szL/), sans the URL and data params which are replaced w/ jsfiddle test data to mimic the AJAX request.

```
(function demo(iteration) {
    count = iteration || 0;
  
  if (count < 3) {
    $.when(testPromise(count).promise())
        .done(function () {
        doSomething();
        })
      .always(function () {
        demo(count + 1);
        });
  }
})();

function doSomething() {
    console.log("something!");
}

function testPromise(iteration) {
  var deferred = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/echo/json/',
    data: {
      json: JSON.stringify({ "data": "Data!" }),
      delay: 0.1
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function () {
            console.log("Before Send: " + iteration);
    },
    success: function(response) {
      console.log("Success: " + iteration);
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("Error: " + iteration);
    },
    complete: function () {
        console.log("Complete: " + iteration);
    }
  });
  
  return deferred;
}
```

Now, the Jsfiddle makes the following print statements:

[image: jsfiddle output]

However, my local code makes an alternative set of print statements:

[image: local output]

You'll notice that the jsfiddle consecutive AJAX requests are issued and completed in order, but the local output shows that consecutive requests are issued before the previous one completes: *Before Send: 1; Complete: 0* and *Before Send: 2; Complete: 1*.  That is, the Promise callback and Complete callback are not handled in the same order for these two environments.

According to http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/,

> The callback hooks provided by $.ajax() are as follows:
>
> 1. beforeSend callback option is invoked.
> 2. error ...
> 3. dataFilter ...
> 4. success callback option is invoked, if the request succeeds.
> 5. Promise callbacks — .done(), .fail(), .always(), and .then() — are invoked, in the order they are registered.
> 6. complete callback option fires, when the request finishes, whether in failure or success.

Besides the list order, the documentation does not really indicate whether the order of these callbacks is guaranteed and I would suppose that the order is actually not guaranteed given that the jsfiddle and my local code do not reconcile.

So what is happening under the covers to produce these two different results?  And suppose I wanted my local code to behave like the jsfiddle (Complete handled before Promise) - what changes can I make to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance -

*As a sidenote, I am aware that the following $.when() functionality can be achieved via the AJAX .complete() handler.  I have intentionally made the AJAX function agnostic to the conditions for which it would need to be called as the end goal I have is to make a generic queue'ing module which will handle queue processing and call a given deferrable function as necessary.  So, the AJAX .complete() method is not available to me for this purpose.*

```
$.when(testPromise(count).promise())
    .done(function () {
        doSomething();
    })
    .always(function () {
        demo(count + 1);
    });
```

Comment: ajax is asynchronous. The server can impact the order that responses are received in which is likely why you are getting different results in jsfiddle compared to your own server.

Comment: that is true, although I wouldn't expect the server response to matter in this situation since each subsequent request is dependent on the previous request's deferred object having already resolved.  So b/c only one ajax request has a deferred object state of "pending" at any given time, the server should be irrelevant.  Please correct me if I'm wrong but I appreciate the input!

Comment: If that is the case, then yeah the server's response would be irrelevant. Can you provide the relevant code in your question?

Comment: Everything is in that jsfiddle

Comment: Assuming both locations are using the same version of jquery, I can't explain why one would give different results than the other in this case.

Comment: Note that there are a number of libraries which handle queues of Promises. If you were to adapt your code to return `deferred.promise()` instead of a `Deferred`, you could use those.

Comment: As HumbleRat pointed out, there was a breaking change in JQuery 3.0 to make jQuery deferred become 'Promises/A+ compatible'.  This explains the inconsistency between my environment and the jsfiddle.  Thx @Kevin_B also for clueing me into the possibility that versioning could be to blame.  Seems obvious now but I just did not even think to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Deferred was updated in version 3.0 (https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/), so making sure your jQuery version is the same as on the fiddle (3.2.1) may help.

Comment: Huh, yep - well I didn't anticipate versioning to be an issue as the deferred object documentation did not mention a mechanics change from 2.X to 3.X but you are absolutely correct.  My environ is on 2.2 and when I bump the jsfiddle down to 2.4 it behaves exactly like my local codebase.  Silly me.  Thanks for the reply